# Testing an application, having signal handling for SIGABRT

Tags: unit-testing, signals, sigabrt

I have an application written in C++ and I have recently installed a signal handler for SIGABRT. Now the job of the signal handler is to catch SIGABRT and print some messages to the user and continue with processing (and not terminate the application)

Now my problem is, how do i test this?

One of the ways i have thought about testing it is by having some random asserts inside the code. But can anyone suggest a more automated way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using the raise function, send the signal to that process.

```
int raise(int sig);

raise(SIGABRT);
```

Or else use the kill funcion.

```
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);

kill(getpid(),SIGABRT);
```